# Line Spacing for Individual Fonts

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm using custom fonts in WordPress. I do it by defining font family.  I'm having problem if line spacing with One if my fonts. If I use line-height code in my custom css I'd theme, it's applied to all the fonts which isn't required. I just want to change line spacing of problematic font. Can we define line spacing for a font while defining its font family?

Best Regards

Comment: Why can't you define the `line-height` for wherever you are using that problematic `font-family`?

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. Please show a snippet of your HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement `font-family` with `line-height` in one class. I mean something like this:

HTML:

```
 <div class="lato-font">Text</div>
 <div class="monospace-font">Text</div>
```

CSS:

```
.lato-font {
    font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.6;
}
.monospace-font {
    font-family: monospace, serif;
    line-height: 1.6;
}
```

In this case you can set custom line-height for each font.

Comment: You declared a class, but do not use it anywhere. Try to add this class for any HTML element on your page like: `<span class="PakNastaleeq-font">Text</span>`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes by defining there, I can adjust my line spacing. But by this way I've to declare class for every text. I use fonto plugin in WordPress by which I select font of text in WYSIWYG editor of WordPress. Now to adjust it's line spacing, I have to go to text editor of WordPress and define line spacing.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to define line-height for each element or class that uses the custom font.

```
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,.lead-text,.some-other-class,li {
  font-family: ######;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I tried using the above code but didn't get the results. Then I declared class of my font as Alex recommended and used the class in my post.